# Spring boot @transactional does not roll back

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am using Spring boot and trying to set transactions to work properly.

This is my main class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.aa.bb")
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
@Path("/users")
public class UserRestServices {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private LogRecordDao logRecordDao;

    @POST
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public String saveUser(User user) {

        userDao.create(user);   
        logUser(user);

        return "SUCCESS";   
    }

    private void logUser(User user) {

        LogRecord log = new LogRecord();

        log.setClassName(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        log.setText("User was created " + user.getName());
            logRecordDao.create(log);
    }
}
```

The create user works well as it should.

The logUser in the logRecordDao is implemented for exception:

```
public void create(LogRecord entity) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("UPDATE AAA SET lll = 3");
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

There is no such table therefore I expect a rollback.
There isn't any.

The user is saved even though an exception occured:

Log:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (name, userName) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    UPDATE
        AAA 
    SET
        lll = 3
2015-09-12 13:35:28.645  WARN 34974 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2015-09-12 13:35:28.646 ERROR 34974 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'db.AAA' doesn't exist
```

I tried to set @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
id

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?